# How do I stop new data from python replacing old data in a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, export-to-csv

OK, so I'm trying to get input from the user and store it in a csv file (I'm using microsoft excel) under the headers of 'username' and 'password'. I've successfully done this using the DictWriter command, but when I try again with different data, it just replaces the previous data. In short, I want to find a way to put the new data in a new row, under the same headers.

my code looks like this:

```
name = input("enter you name")
age = input("enter your age in years")
username = name[:3] + age
print("your unique username is", username)
while True:
    password = input("enter a password over 6 characters")
    count = 0
    for letter in password:
        count = count + 1
    if count < 6:
        print("password too short, please enter another")
    else:
        break


import csv

with open('usernames.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['username', 'password']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'username': username, 'password': password})
```

when i run it, it works:

```
============ RESTART: /Users/Hesta/Desktop/python csv/username.py ============
enter you namejohn smith
enter your age in years19
your unique username is joh19
enter a password over 6 characterslongpassword
>>>
```

This data gets sent to a csv file under the headers 'username' and 'password'.
However, if I run the code again, and enter different data, it works again, but completely replaces the previously entered data. How do I make it so that the new data is stored on a different row?

Comment: `with open('usernames.csv', 'a', newline='')` use the `a`ppend mode.